# How to remove an array value from another array using PHP question

Tags: php

I want to check if any of the array values from example 1 are in example 2 and remove them from example 2 if they are. How would I be able to do this using PHP?

Example 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
)
```

Example 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 4
    [9] => 4
    [10] => 4
    [11] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$example2 = array_diff($example2, $example1)`

Answer (score 7):

`$array = array_diff($array2, $array1);`

[`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) computes the difference between arrays.  It returns an array containing all the entries from the first array that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($example2 as $key => $value) {
   foreach($example1 as $key1 => $value1) {
      if ($value1 == $value) {
         unset($example2[$key])
      }
   }
}
```